# Transform a triangle into a square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, change-of-variable

Let $T$  be the triangle  bounded by

[image]
$$
x=0,\\
 y=0,\\ 
x+y=1
$$

Is there such a change of variables
$$u=f_1(x,y),\\v=f_2(x,y)$$
(or a sequence of such changes) that transforms this triangle into the square  $u=0,u=1, v=0,v=1$?

[image]

I have been trying to find these transformations, but I have not been able to do so yet.

Comment: Reflect the triangle across its hypotenuse and take the union of those two sets.

Comment: @JohnDouma That's not a function as requested.

Comment: Sometimes duplicating the triangle (as suggested in a previous comment) is a better choice. It really depends on why you need a square.

Comment: There are numerous ways you could stretch the triangle (possibly also with rotation) to fill the square. Also you can cut a reassemble the triangle.

Comment: @ David K   I need  it to change variables in a double integral.

Answer (score 2):

An intuitive solution would be to imagine the triangle as elastic, and pull the $(1/2,1/2)$ point to $(1,1)$. For every original point $(x,y)$ you calculate the polar angle $\theta$, you calculate the intersection of the line at angle $\theta$ with the $x+y+=1$ line, you calculate the intersection of the radial line with $x=1$ and $y=1$ lines, and scale the original $(x,y)$ by the ratio of the lengths to $x=1$ (or $y=1$, as appropriate) and length to $x+y=1$. Can you take it from here?

**EDIT:**

Let the intersection of $(0,0)\to(x,y)$ line be $(x_s,y_s)$, the intersection with $x=1$ be $(1,y_1)$, and the intersection with $y=1$ be $(x_1,1)$. To calculate these points, we just write the equations:
$$\frac xy=\frac{x_s}{y_s}=\frac{x_1}1=\frac{1}{y_1}$$
This allow us to immediately say $$x_1=\frac xy\\y_1=\frac yx$$
For $x_s,y_s$ we also need to use $$x_s+y_s=1$$
Then $$y_s=\frac yx x_s\\x_s\left(1+\frac yx\right)=1\\x_s=\frac{x}{x+y}\\y_s=\frac{y}{x+y}$$
With these, the length of $(0,0)\to(x_s,y_s)$ is $$L_s=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x+y}$$
The length of $(0,0)\to(1,y_1)$ is $$L_{y_1}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}$$ and similarly $$L_{x_1}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$$
So for points with $x\gt y$ we scale both $x$ and $y$ by $$\frac{L_{y_1}}{L_s}=\frac{x+y}x$$
For $y\gt x$ the scale factor is $$\frac{L_{x_1}}{L_s}=\frac{x+y}y$$
Therefore $$u=x\frac{x+y}{\max(x,y)}\\v=y\frac{x+y}{\max(x,y)}$$

Comment: No, please explane

Comment: Done. There are other solutions as well.

Comment: Thank you................